# How to uninstall Eclipse Mars which was installed using Oomph installer?

Tags: centos7, eclipse-mars, oomph

I installed Eclipse Mars using Oomph installer on Centos 7. How do I uninstall it cleanly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As root you could use whereis and locate to find all the directories or files where things are, and then remove them one by one.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. It looks like removing manually is the only way to do it.

Comment: From what I know, there's at least 3 folders that can be removed.


The Eclipse installation folder can obviously be removed.


~/.p2 is used to share features and plugins between many Eclipse installations done with Oomph. The folder can be removed, but that could break other Eclipse installations if there's some.
~/.eclipse : A folder that contains (among other things) the Oomph profile of the current user. The main reason to remove it is to reset the preferences stored with the Oomph Preference Recorder, since they will be reused if Eclipse is reinstalled with Oomph.

Comment: @Marc-André Consider answering the question with the information in your comment. It surely helped me. Thanks.